# Design of a dialog box

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to design a dialog box in WPF (Similar to Image 1). I am using below code in my main dialog page,

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>

    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Fill="#ebebeb"></Rectangle>
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Fill="#ebebeb"></Rectangle>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Margin="20">
        <VPASDC:AgentHintControl x:Name="agentHintControl" Margin="0 0 0 10"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="20">

        <VPASDC:AgentScriptControl x:Name="agentScriptControl" Margin="0 0 0 10"/>
        <VPASDC:AgentQuestionControl x:Name="agentQuestionControl" Margin="0 0 0 10"/>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,0,0" x:Name="ValidationGrid" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="/AgentScripting;component/Images/baseline-error-24px.png" Height="20px" Width="20px" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource AgentScriptDialogValidatiorErrorTextBlockStyle}" Margin="25 0 0 0" x:Name="tbValidationErrorMessage" >
                Invalid Entry. Card Last 4 digits Must be Numeric</TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>



    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="19.8,9.6,20.4,-9.6" Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button x:Name="OkButton" Grid.Column="0" Style="{DynamicResource AgentScriptingDialogButtons}" Margin="0 0 30 0" Click="OkButton_Click">
            <TextBlock Text="OK" />
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="NextButton" Grid.Column="1"  Style="{DynamicResource AgentScriptingDialogButtons}" Margin="30 0 00 0" Click="NextButton_Click" >
            <TextBlock Text="NEXT"  />
        </Button>
    </Grid>


</Grid>
```

And inside my agentHintControl.xaml page which is the tip area on the left hand side of the image is being made through below xaml code.

```
<Grid  Background="#ebebeb">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="55"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition ></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <!--Source="/AgentScripting;component/Images/ikon01.png"-->
    <Image Grid.Column="0" 
           Source="C:\Projects\AgentScripting_30102018\AgentScripting\AgentScripting\Images\TIPIcon.png"
           Height="auto"
           Width="auto"
           Stretch="Fill"
           VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"  Grid.Row="0" Height="Auto"
               Margin="10 0 0 0"
               FontFamily="Segoe UI Bold" FontSize="18"
               Text="TIP" />
    <TextBlock Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" Height="Auto"
               Margin="10 0 0 0"
               Style="{DynamicResource AgentScriptDialogHintTextBlockStyle}" 
               Text="Get information for suspicious transactions from customer" x:Name="txtAgentHint"/>
</Grid>
```

**Image 1: (What i want to achieve)**
[image: This is the image i want to get]

**Image 2: (What I am getting)**

[image]

Now, as can be seen in image 2, my problem is i am getting to much white spaces. What i mean is that the dialog should adjust it size according to the content on the dialog. But in image 2 there are too many white spaces. In my Windows i am using **SizeToContent ="HeightandWidth"**. It is adjusting the width all right but not the height.

Looking forward to your help.

Comment: Maybe this line:  `<Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Fill="#ebebeb"></Rectangle>`  You only have 2 rows in the grid, so with 0-based index the last row is #1.  I would look at the xaml and add col # and row # to controls wherever they are missing, and to help with finding the issue, give `Width`s to all `ColumnDefinition`s and `Height`s to all `RowDefinition`s

Comment: I corrected it <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Fill="#ebebeb"></Rectangle> but still it is the same.

Comment: Can you update the code in the example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple issues on first glance, the `Grid.Row="2"` attribute I mentioned in comments, and your validation grid is in a `StackPanel`, so the `Grid.Column` attribute isn't relevant.  I'm also not sure what your rectangles do - are they for background colour?

In any event, however, your grid definitions look more complicated than the grid actually is.  Try:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition />
    <ColumnDefinition />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Fill="#ebebeb"></Rectangle>  <!-- maybe remove this and provide a `Background` attribute for the StackPanel below -->
  <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Margin="20">
    <VPASDC:AgentHintControl x:Name="agentHintControl" Margin="0 0 0 10"/>
  </StackPanel>

  <Grid Grid.Column="1">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="20">
      <VPASDC:AgentScriptControl x:Name="agentScriptControl" Margin="0 0 0 10"/>
      <VPASDC:AgentQuestionControl x:Name="agentQuestionControl" Margin="0 0 0 10"/>
      <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" x:Name="ValidationGrid" Visibility="Collapsed">
        <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="/AgentScripting;component/Images/baseline-error-24px.png" Height="20px" Width="20px" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource AgentScriptDialogValidatiorErrorTextBlockStyle}" Margin="25 0 0 0" x:Name="tbValidationErrorMessage">
            Invalid Entry. Card Last 4 digits Must be Numeric
        </TextBlock>
      </Grid>
    </StackPanel>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="19.8,9.6,20.4,-9.6" >
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

      <Button x:Name="OkButton" Grid.Column="0" Style="{DynamicResource AgentScriptingDialogButtons}" Margin="0 0 30 0" Click="OkButton_Click">
        <TextBlock Text="OK" />
      </Button>
      <Button x:Name="NextButton" Grid.Column="1"  Style="{DynamicResource AgentScriptingDialogButtons}" Margin="30 0 00 0" Click="NextButton_Click" >
        <TextBlock Text="NEXT"  />
      </Button>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
<Grid>
```

For xaml debugging, I tend to add vivid colours to backgrounds, and include border attributes so I can see exactly where the controls are.

Comment: Thanks. This solution worked well for me. The only change i made was set the width of first column to 200 because it was getting out of shape otherwise worked well.